# How do I stop messages appearing on the homescreen of my iPad2?

Tags: messages

How do I stop iMessages from appearing automatically on my home screen?
Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

Settings -> Notifications -> Messages.  Set Alert Style to None.